# git commit shows untracked files

Tags: git, github, commit

I want to commit my files and type this command

> git commit -a -m "all base files"

it shows some untracked files that contains files I want to track.. 
I need to commit html files, checked gitignore files but cant find why its untracked.. why they are untracked? how git decided himself to not track these files? how can I commit files I choose in this list ? 
here is ss:
[image]

Comment: You never called `git add` for this files

Comment: It didn't *"decided himself to not track"* them, but *you didn't tell it to*. Also I'd recommend a more thoughtful approach than blindly committing every change; use e.g. `git add -p` to interactively review and stage your changes.

Comment: run git add . and try again. Also make sure you are not ignoring them in your .gitignore

Comment: @Jens yeah I forced it and done now.. stackoverflow warn me about not  delete post I can happily accept you or below comments as answer if you wish

Comment: @user5570680 Added it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong here. The **untracked files** simple means git found some file in your local(your PC) which is not present in the remote (git repo), that means you have created new files. To commit this you can do these commands:

**`$git status`**  //optional, this will show all the files which are changed and which have added to next commit and which are not.

**`$git add .`** //this will add all the file which are changed to next commit.

or

**`$git add "filepath"`** //this will add only specific file to next commit.

then

**`$git commit -m "all base files"`**

Answer (score 0):

You never called `git add` for this files